# Elasticsearch Index corrupted after upgrade to 2.1.0

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I have "tried" to upgrade from elasticsearch-1.5.2 to 2.1.0 but after first start attempt my all indexes are corrupted.

Start didnt work so i rolled back to ES-1.5.2.

The Problem is now i cant use indexes, because elasticsearch dies after 2-3 sec.

When i check the indexes with this :

```
java -cp "*" -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex  PATH_TO_INDEX/node/0/indices/INDEX/SHARD/index/
```

I get following error msg:

```
ERROR: could not read any segments file in directory
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource: BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path=.....)
```

When i try to fix the index  (with **-fix**) it also wont work and i get the same msg as above.

I think during the start attempts, elasticsearch-2.1.0 changed some setting in  **"_state" folder** and this could be the reason why i cant use my old indexes.

Any idea how i can fix my indexes ?

Answer (score 0):

It's [strongly advised to back up your indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) **before** doing any upgrade, because once upgraded, you can never downgrade ES.

Also, it would have been a good idea to run the [migration plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration) in order to see if your 1.5 indices were compatible with the 2.1 version. Obviously, it's too late for you, but I'm pointing at this for other SO people looking for the same issue.

You have a few options now:

1. Stay with 1.5 and re-index all your data
2. Go with 2.1 and re-index all your data
3. Retry the 2.1 upgrade on your existing indices and figure out why ES won't start.